Issue with Filter Functionality in React Context API
I'm working on a React project using the Context API to manage state between components. Specifically, I have a filtering functionality that should display campaigns based on selected categories. However, the filtering doesn't seem to work as expected.
Context:

filterState is an array managed by Context API and shared between "All-campaigns" and "Display-campaigns" components.
searchState is another state managed similarly, which works fine.

All-campaigns Component:
The handleFilter function updates filterState when checkboxes are clicked:
const { filterState, setFilterState } = useStateContext();

const handleFilter = (e) => {
    if (e.checked && !filterState.includes(e.id)) {
        setFilterState(prevState => [...prevState, e.id.toLowerCase()]);
    } else {
        setFilterState(prevState => prevState.filter(item => item !== e.id.toLowerCase()));
    }
};

return (
  <div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="medical" id="medical" onChange={(e) => { handleFilter(e.target) }} />
      <label className="ml-1"> Medical </label>
    </div>
    {/* Other checkboxes */}
  </div>
);

Display-campaigns Component:
This component filters campaigns based on filterState and searchState:
const { searchState, filterState } = useStateContext();

return (
  {!isLoading && campaigns.length > 0 &&
    campaigns
      .filter((campaign) => {
        if (searchState === "" && filterState.length === 0) {
          return campaign;
        } else if (
          campaign.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchState.toLowerCase()) ||
          filterState.includes(campaign.category.toLowerCase())
        ) {
          console.log("Inside Filter");
          return campaign;
        }
      })
      .map((campaign) => (
        <FundCard
          key={campaign.id}
          {...campaign}
          handleClick={() => handleNavigate(campaign)}
        />
      ))}
};

Problem:

filterState updates correctly as confirmed by useEffect logging it.
The console.log("Inside Filter"); gets executed, but campaigns are not filtered correctly.
All campaigns are shown by default, even when filters are applied.

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Filter State Updated:", filterState);
}, [filterState]);


Observations:

The filter condition seems correct, but the UI doesn't reflect the filtered results.
console.log("Inside Filter"); executes before the useEffect log.

How can I fix the filtering functionality to display campaigns correctly based on the selected categories?
Additional Details:

The search functionality works as expected.
Both filterState and searchState are managed using the Context API.

Any insights or suggestions on what might be going wrong would be greatly appreciated!
I tried placing filterState in the All-campaigns page instead of using Context API for it and then directly passing it as a prop to the Display-campaigns component but the issue still persisted.
